# ActionBar icon not showing

Tags: android

i have added the menu file:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
        android:title="Refresh"/>
```

but the icon is not showing in the actionbar, dont understand why ?

actionbar is enabled like this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Comment: What icon is not showing the app's  logo or the menu item drawable(refresh)?

Comment: which icon are you talking about action bar icon on top-left or icon for menu ?

Comment: Try adding this to the menu   `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">` or change this  :`android:showAsAction="always"` to :`app:showAsAction="always"`

Comment: i solved it ,via same process as @josef mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your onCreate method

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```